# jsf 1.2 composite component support

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, components, composite-component

Does JSF 1.2 support creating composite components?

Something like:

```
<composite:interface>
    ...
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

or is this available in JSF 2.0?

In JSF 1.2 my only option is using `<ui:component>...</ui:component>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite componets have been introduced in JSF2, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) question to review available alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the question you gave me link to, is also about JSF 2.0.

Comment: Yes, and excellent answer from BalusC compares JSF 2 only composite components to 3 alternative options, all available also in JSF 1.2 :)